# Build a Mockup Application Framework

Tags: user-interface, builder, mockups

I am trying to build an application that will help build mockups. So to be clear I am not looking to build an application using mockups but an application that others can use to build mockups. Do you know of any frameworks out there that I can use to build this? This is an application that should be run as a desktop app. I would have liked to use Flash but dont want to take the chance since this might be ported over to the iPad.

Comment: are you talking about UI mockups?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Balsamiq](http://balsamiq.com/) Mockups?

Comment: Thanks - thats an example of an application I am trying to build. I am interested in knowing if there is a framework that would allow me to build an application like Balsamiq. If not a framework do you know what language Balsamiq was written in?

Comment: please start a question of your own. On Stackoverflow we don't ask questions in the answers sections. (Welcome though, and enjoy SO)